# tesseract detects only 4 words from image

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract, opencv

I have very simple python code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread('1.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

hImg,wImg,_ = img.shape

#detecting words
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_data(img)
for x,b in enumerate(boxes.splitlines()):
    if x!=0:
        b = b.split()
        if len(b) == 12:
            x,y,w,h = int(b[6]), int(b[7]), int(b[8]), int(b[9])
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (w+x,h+y), (0,0,255), 3)


cv2.imshow('result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But result was interesting. It detected only 4 words. what could it be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have better OCR results if you [`improve the quality`](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) of the image you are giving Tesseract.

> While tesseract version 3.05 (and older) handle inverted image (dark background and light text) without problem, for 4.x version use dark text on light background.

Convert from `BGR` to `HLS` to later remove background colors from  the numbers in the top half of the image. Then, create a "blue" mask with `cv2.inRange` and replace anything that's not "blue" with  the color white.

```py
hls=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)

# Define lower and upper limits for the number colors.
blue_lo=np.array([114, 70, 70])
blue_hi=np.array([154, 225, 225])

# Mask image to only select "blue"
mask=cv2.inRange(hls,blue_lo,blue_hi)

# copy original image
img1 = img.copy()
img1[mask==0]=(255,255,255)
```

Help pytesseract by converting the image to black and white

> This is converting an image to black and white. Tesseract does this internally (Otsu algorithm), but the result can be suboptimal, particularly if the page background is of uneven darkness.

```py
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_HLS2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_, img1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('img_to_binary',img1)
```

[image: binary_image]

Use `image_to_data` over the previously created `img1` and continue applying your existing code.

```py
...
hImg,wImg,_ = img.shape

#detecting words
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_data(img1)
for x,b in enumerate(boxes.splitlines()):
    ...
...
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you. You solved my problem